# How to rewrite a request using jetty

Tags: angular, jetty, jetty-9

I have set up a standalone Jetty Server (version 9.4.19) and deployed an Angular 8 application to it. 
The base href looks like this: `<base href="/myapp/">`.

I can access the application via `<server-ip>:8080/myapp/`. 
I know, that I have to implement a rewrite rule for the jetty to direct any requests in the form of `<server-ip>:8080/myapp/*` back to the index.html in order for angular to handle the request.

I activated the rewrite module (`java -jar start.jar add-to-start=rewrite`). I then edited the `jetty-rewrite.xml`file and tried to add a rule. The file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- configure rewrite handler                                   -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call name="insertHandler">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
        <Set name="rewriteRequestURI"><Property name="jetty.rewrite.rewriteRequestURI" deprecated="rewrite.rewriteRequestURI" default="true"/></Set>
        <Set name="rewritePathInfo"><Property name="jetty.rewrite.rewritePathInfo" deprecated="rewrite.rewritePathInfo" default="false"/></Set>
        <Set name="originalPathAttribute"><Property name="jetty.rewrite.originalPathAttribute" deprecated="rewrite.originalPathAttribute" default="requestedPath"/></Set>

        <!-- Set DispatcherTypes  -->
        <Set name="dispatcherTypes">
          <Array type="javax.servlet.DispatcherType">
            <Item><Call class="javax.servlet.DispatcherType" name="valueOf"><Arg>REQUEST</Arg></Call></Item>
            <Item><Call class="javax.servlet.DispatcherType" name="valueOf"><Arg>ASYNC</Arg></Call></Item>
          </Array>
        </Set>

        <!--<Get id="Rewrite" name="ruleContainer"/>-->

        <Call name="addRule">
          <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewritePatternRule">
              <Set name="pattern">/myapp/*</Set>
              <Set name="replacement">/myapp/</Set>
            </New>
          </Arg>
        </Call>

        <!-- see rewrite-compactpath.xml for example how to add a rule -->

      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

When I refresh the page within my application, I get an 404 error message. I guess that means, that the rewriting doesn't work.

I tried to change the rewriting target to `<Set name="replacement">/</Set>` and `<Set name="replacement">/myapp/index.html</Set>`, but that didn't work either.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**

I found out: When I change the pattern for the RewritePatternRule to a specific part of my application (e.g. `<Set name="pattern">/myapp/dashboard</Set>`) and refresh from that page, the rewriting works fine, but not from other parts of the application.

Answer (score 0):

The `RewritePatternRule` will rewrite the pattern portion, leaving the `pathInfo` portion alone.

If you set the logging level to DEBUG for `org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite` you'll see ...

```
[DEBUG]:oejrh.RuleContainer: applied org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewritePatternRule[ht][/myapp/*][/myapp/]
[DEBUG]:oejrh.RuleContainer: rewrote /myapp/alt.html to /myapp/alt.html
```

If you switch to `RewriteRegexRule` you can control things a bit better.

Example setup ...

```sh
$ mkdir ~/rewrite-test-base
$ cd ~/rewrite-test-base/
[rewrite-test-base]$ java -jar ~/jetty-home-9.4.20.v20190813/start.jar --add-to-start=http,deploy,rewrite,resources
INFO  : webapp          transitively enabled, ini template available with --add-to-start=webapp
INFO  : server          transitively enabled, ini template available with --add-to-start=server
INFO  : security        transitively enabled
INFO  : servlet         transitively enabled
INFO  : http            initialized in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO  : threadpool      transitively enabled, ini template available with --add-to-start=threadpool
INFO  : bytebufferpool  transitively enabled, ini template available with --add-to-start=bytebufferpool
INFO  : rewrite         initialized in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO  : deploy          initialized in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
MKDIR : ${jetty.base}/webapps
INFO  : Base directory was modified

# Setup the rewrite rules
$ cd ~/rewrite-test-base
$ mkdir etc
$ cp ~/tmp/my-rewrite.xml etc/
$ echo "etc/my-rewrite.xml" >> start.ini

# Create some content to work with
$ cd ~/rewrite-test-base
$ mkdir webapps/myapp
$ echo "This is the index.html" > webapps/myapp/index.html
$ echo "This you shouldn't be able to access" > webapps/myapp/alt.html

# Now start the server.
$ cd ~/rewrite-test-base
$ java -jar ~/jetty-home-9.4.20.v20190813/start.jar
2019-09-19 13:40:46.582:INFO::main: Logging initialized @331ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2019-09-19 13:40:46.619:INFO:oeju.TypeUtil:main: JVM Runtime does not support Modules
2019-09-19 13:40:46.668:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Deprecated method public void org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration.setBlockingTimeout(long) in file:///home/joakim/jetty-home-9.4.20.v20190813/etc/jetty.xml
2019-09-19 13:40:46.744:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.20.v20190813; built: 2019-08-13T21:28:18.144Z; git: 84700530e645e812b336747464d6fbbf370c9a20; jvm 1.8.0_222-b10
2019-09-19 13:40:46.757:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///home/joakim/rewrite-test-base/webapps/] at interval 1
2019-09-19 13:40:46.816:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /myapp, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2019-09-19 13:40:46.823:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2019-09-19 13:40:46.823:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2019-09-19 13:40:46.824:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2019-09-19 13:40:46.837:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2758fe70{myapp,/myapp,file:///home/joakim/rewrite-test-base/webapps/myapp/,AVAILABLE}{/home/joakim/rewrite-test-base/webapps/myapp}
```

The **my-rewrite.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RuleContainer">
  <Call name="addRule">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteRegexRule">
        <Set name="regex">/myapp/.*$</Set>
        <Set name="replacement">/myapp/</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

Testing it out ...

```sh
$ curl -vvv http://localhost:8080/myapp/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /myapp/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Sep 2019 18:35:54 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 23
< Server: Jetty(9.4.20.v20190813)
< 
This is the index.html
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

$ curl -vvv http://localhost:8080/myapp/alt.html
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /myapp/alt.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Sep 2019 18:35:54 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 23
< Server: Jetty(9.4.20.v20190813)
< 
This is the index.html
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

$ curl -vvv http://localhost:8080/myapp/afdjklafjdskal
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /myapp/afdjklafjdskal HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Sep 2019 18:35:54 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 23
< Server: Jetty(9.4.20.v20190813)
< 
This is the index.html
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Using regex makes sense to me. After i change the rewrite rule to your suggestion, i get the following errors in the dev console of my browser:

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

and for every js file, a message is displayed that the script was loaded although its mime-type is not correct. 
I read that this can happen when jetty tries to serve js files as html files or something like that. 
Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: The browser is still requesting `/myapp/foo.js` and the internal request mechanism still contains that detail.  Perhaps you want to switch from `RewriteRegexRule` to `RedirectRegexRule` forcing a 302 redirect back to the browser.   Ultimately what you are trying to do is a rather odd, you essentially don't want the browser to ever request anything but index.html (no js, no images, no other html, nothing else ever).

Comment: A more sane approach is for your app to have a `Filter` that checks the `Referer` header and if it's blank, force a 302 redirect back to `/myapp/` location.

Comment: Okay, I see the flaw in my logic. I found [examples for other servers](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) where a request for the js files are allowed and only if it's not a resource, the request gets redirected to index.html. I try to achieve the same thing with jetty. 
If that is not possible, I will have to try your suggestion and handle it in the application.

Comment: You could setup a servlet error page handling so that a 404 is always a fixed url `/redirect-to-root` which is a Servlet of yours that just issues a 302 redirect to whatever your root path is (such as `/myapp/`)

Comment: So there is no standard way to just redirect unfitting request when using jetty? 
Or am I just misunderstanding the whole situation?

Comment: "unfitting requests"? no.  rewrite occurs before all handling.  I still think your best bet would be a Error page handling on 404 status.